# How can I log in to the GUI to start deploying services?

Tags: juju, openstack

I installed Juju agent locally and installed the juju gui as well locally.
I'm trying to see where can I log in to the GUI from but it doesn't say...
How can I log in to the GUI to start deploying services?

Answer (score 2):

To find the ip/hostname of the GUI you first must run `juju status` in the command line and it will output the list of services which have been deployed to the active environment. Visit this path and then the GUI will tell you where to look for the password.

If you do this on a remote cloud you will need to run `juju expose juju-gui` to first expose it to the world. This is not required when deploying to your local machine.

If you deployed it locally the password will likely be available by running `head ~/.juju/environments/local.env`

You should also take a look at the `juju-quickstart` plugin which can handle setting up the environment, deploying the GUI, and then opening up the browser and logging you in.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to point your browser to http://*IP juju-gui*/. To figure out the IP just run `juju status juju-gui` and remember to open the port where juju-gui is running with `juju expose juju-gui`

You can find more details at https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/controllers-gui